# Não adicionar á database quando algum valor for null

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Como faço para não adicionar á database quando a String dia for null ?

Código :

```
      public boolean insertData(String disciplina,String sala,String dia,String hora){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_2,disciplina);
    values.put(COL_3,sala);
    values.put(COL_4,dia);
    values.put(COL_5,hora);
    long result = database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        if(result==-1){
            return false;
        }else
            return true;


}
```

Comment: NOT NULL na  coluna do database

Comment: Como assim ? Pode elaborar numa resposta ?

Comment: na criação da tabela do database, tem column Name Datatype NOT NULLl Flags Default Value Comment, só assinalar NOT NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem 2 opções:

1) Definir na criação da tabela que a coluna não pode receber nulos e, caso tente inserir nulo, o banco coloca um valor default. Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (coluna TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'texto qualquer');
```

2) Definir na criação da tabela que a coluna não pode receber nulos e o método que insere tem que checar antes e abortar, caso o valor seja nulo. Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (coluna TEXT NOT NULL);
```

No método:

```
public boolean insertData(String valor_coluna){
    if(valor_coluna == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(valor_coluna)) return false;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(coluna, valor_coluna);

    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Exatamente como eu havia pensado. Mesmo assim é mais indicado alterar a database e o metodo que faz a inserção.

Comment: São 2 estratégias diferentes. Tem casos que você quer setar um valor default  e não precisar se importar com a inserção (tipo dados que provavelmente você preencheria a maioria com o valor default mesmo, então mais fácil inserir um nulo e o banco corrige) ou tem casos que não pode ser nulo e você não quer mesmo um valor default.